# SQL Query to Get Standard Deviation for a Group and Total At The Same time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a scenario very similar to this:
Table recording each sales deal for a particular employee.
The data I would require should be grouped by the employee and should have the standard deviation of sales generated by the employee and the standard deviation for all employees and all sales based on initial table and not aggregated group-by data.

If it had been totals, i.e. using sums it should look something like this:

```
SELECT
    employee,
    SUM (employees.sales ) AS "employee sales",
    SUM(SUM (employees.sales)) OVER () AS "total sales"
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    employee
```

The specifics of my case are such that I cannot really use subqueries.
Would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: I assume you want the standard deviation of the aggregated sales.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I guess it can very well be read that way. Updated the question with hopefully better wording.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you just want the `STDDEV()` window function:

```
SELECT employee,
       SUM(employees.sales ) AS employee_sales,
       SUM(SUM(employees.sales)) OVER () AS total_sales,
       STDDEV(SUM(employees.sales)) OVER () AS stddev_sales
FROM employees
GROUP BY employee;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I would need TWO standard deviations - one for sales of the particular employee, and one for all employees.